# I think I broke my phone while trying to root it

Tags: rooting, samsung, root-access

I tried rooting my phone a few minutes ago and it ended up erasing my data but now it keeps trying to reboot but it never makes it past the "Samsung galaxy j5 prime" screen. help? is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Could you include the steps that you did?

Comment: You have bricked it.You have to flash Stock ROM.Download the Stock ROM for Samsung galaxy j5 prime and Burn it.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung's are notoriously hard to gain root access on, and many people that own a Samsung prefer to use a separate device with root access.

The main reson is that Samsung's main goal ( in my opinion ) was to create a device that is secure enough to be used by law enforcement agencies.

The main selling point in that direction was a security feature called Knox, .. Knox is supposed to stop any modifications that could expose the devices sensitive data, if you do gain root access, it is usually by removing knox or disabling it somehow.

Usually to do this is to exploit the system and a specific vulnerability that will allow root access.

Gaining root access on a Samsung will disable many features that require a secure device, like payment methods for example.

You need to use a program called Odin to restore your Stock Firmware and then consider either using a different device or using a custom firmware that has root access already.